# Finding a mode or most frequently seen number from list to array c++

Tags: c++

I am working on online gdb and my problem is that, given random numbers in a text file, I need a program that would save these numbers into an array and then I need to display the mode.

Here are the numbers 
50
28
84
41
52
22
22
74
33
93
85
73
36
86
49
7
53
85
46
2
53
36
43
38
13
43
30
12
41
69
70
91
84
77
35
51
13
33
92
75
16
18
69
26
49
35
93
72
16
88
84

I have done the first two parts and they work. My problem is finding the mode.

Here's my code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

//function prototype 
void calculateMode(int [], int );

//**************
//*Main function
//* has getting text file then storing into array and then function to finding the mode 
//************
int main ()
{
    const int ARRAY_SIZE = 51; // constant so we can use it outside of main 
    int numbers [ARRAY_SIZE];
    int count = 0; // loop counter varible 
    ifstream inputFile; // input file stream object 

    //opening the file 
    inputFile.open("file.txt");

    //reading the numbers from the file then putting it into the array 
    while (count < ARRAY_SIZE && inputFile >> numbers [count])
    count ++;

    // closing file
    inputFile.close();

    // calling on our function for calculating mode 
    calculateMode(numbers, ARRAY_SIZE); 

    return 0;
}

//*********
//* Calculating the mode funtion 
//* calculates mode and then displays it 
//*********
void calculateMode(int ARRAY_SIZE[], int size)
{
        int counter = 0; // loop counter varible 
        int max = 0; // using this for maximum value for an object of type int so it can hold a lot 
        int mode = ARRAY_SIZE[0]; 
        for (int pass = 0; pass < size - 1; pass++) 
        {
           for (  ) // for loop suppose to be here 
           {
              counter++;
              if ( counter > max )
              {
                  max = counter;
                  mode = ARRAY_SIZE[pass]; // not sure if this algorithm for finding mode is correct 
              }
           } else 
              counter = 1; // reset counter.
        }
    cout << "The mode is " << mode << endl; // cout the mode 
}
```

As you can see in my function for the mode I don't know where to start after the for. I am supposed to have two for loops. Also, I don't know if my algorithm because when I checked it before I had an if statement that would check the value of each number. Then I got 22 because they were next together in the text file.

Any help is appreciated, Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you explain the definition of "the mode"?

Comment: I meant to put these two at the begging, #include <iostream> and #include <fstream>, instead of the two blank ones.

Comment: The mode is the number that is the most frequently seen in the list.

Comment: Use a `std::map<int,int>` or `std::unordered_map<int, int>`.  This would be no more than a few lines of code.

Comment: You can [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/55287159/edit) your question to make it better instead of describing its shortcomings in comments. I suggest that you change "_the mode_" to "_the most frequently seen number_" or something similar.

Comment: @Aspext -- What if there is more than one mode?

Comment: The mode is supposed to be 84

Comment: @Aspext I know that the mode for your data is 84.  What if the data is "2 2 4 4"?  Is 2 the mode, or is 4 the mode, as both 2 and 4 appear twice.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how can i find a mode for only one number?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55231773/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your values are always 0 - 99 like your example, this body for calculateMode() would suffice:

```
    void calculateMode(int ARRAY_SIZE[], int size)
    {
        int MODE_COUNTER[100] = { 0 };
        int mode = 0;
        int max = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
            if (++MODE_COUNTER[ARRAY_SIZE[i]] > max)
            {
                mode = ARRAY_SIZE[i];
                max = MODE_COUNTER[ARRAY_SIZE[i]];
            }

        cout << "The mode is " << mode << endl; // cout the mode 
    }
```

But an ideal solution would have a dynamic MODE_COUNTER[] object. I would use a `vector<pair<int,int>>`

Comment: Thank you so much I understand my mistakes now.

Comment: @Aspext if the values can be any replace the array by a map, the algorithm is similar (I upvoted that solution ^^)